# Formatting small decimal numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formatting

How can I format the number `0.00935349` in a string using `fprintf()` so that I can display [image]?

Comment: Do you want to write to a file or display this?

Answer (score 2):

The `%e` [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) gets you close:

```
>> fprintf('%.1e\n', 0.00935349)
9.4e-03
```

If you want the `e` to appear as `x10`, you can use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to generate the number string, replace the `e` using [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) on the result, then pass that to [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html):

```
>> fprintf(strrep(sprintf('%.1e\n', 0.00935349), 'e', 'x10'))
9.4x10-03
```